# Pular página de 5 em 5 Blocos

Tags: php, html, css

Boa tarde,

Estou retornando dados de uma tabela e mostrando no CSS, porém eu preciso exibir 5 blocos por página e a cada 5 blocos preciso inserir um trecho de código para forçar o navegador a ir para outra página.

Exemplo:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($busca)){
echo "<div class='bloco'>
<p class'nome'>FULANO</p>
<address>Endereço</addess>  
</div>";    
}
```

Gostaria que quando fosse mostrado 5 blocos, eu possa inserir esta linha abaixo

```
<div style="page-break-before: always !important"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode incrementar um contador e verificar se ele é múltiplo de 5 a cada passagem do laço.

```
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($busca)){
    echo "<div class='bloco'>
    <p class'nome'>FULANO</p>
    <address>Endereço</addess>  
    </div>";
    if($i % 5 === 0) echo '<div style="page-break-before: always !important"></div>';    
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Só tome cuidado com ifs sem `{}`.

Comment: Conseguiu elaborar?

Comment: Deu certo amigos, show de bola!
Minha primeira postagem aqui no fórum, costumava usar o Imasters, mais lá está muito parado. Obrigado!!